# android: как вернуться в предыдущее activity без потери данных второго

Tags: java, android, android-studio

есть 2 активити А1 и А2 перехожу из А1 в А2 с помощью Intent, когда нужно вернуться обратно в А1 вызываю метод finish(), но тогда все данные А2 сотрутся, можно ли как то этого избежать и скакать между двумя активити без потери данных в каждом из них?

Comment: Посмотри вот этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136297/switching-between-activities-without-losing-custom-data

Comment: Не надо использовать finish() и нажимать кнопку "Назад" (если она отдельно не перехвачена).
Вместо этого есть фрагменты.